# laravel 5.2 only retrieves numeric value from ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am using ajax to submit my form, and I noticed that only the numeric values are passed since when I checked before submitting the form the variables are all populated. but when they reach my controller only the numeric ones get trough.

AJAX:

```
function approveForm(id){
            var mystring, stringie, approvier, tokens;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + '/approveForm',
                data: {id:id, "_token": token},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    stringie = data.toString();
                    mystring = stringie.replace(/[,]/g, '');
                    $("#myModal3 .modal-content").html(mystring);
                    approvier = $('#approvier').val();
                    tokens = $("input[name=_token]").val();
                    $('#myFmeaForm').on('submit', function(e){
                        alert(id);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: baseUrl + '/verifyForm',
                            data: {id:id, approvier: approvier, "_token": tokens},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(data){
                                alert(data);
                                if(data){
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }   
            }); 
        }
```

my controller:

```
public function verifyForm(){

        return Input::get('approvier');
    }
```

I tried using numeric and alphanumeric for the approvier variable and it goes trough when its numeric but not when its aplhanumeric

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this in general is to serialise the form anyway.....

This is the jquery reference, but standard JS has it also:

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

So your:
data: {id:id, "_token": token},

Becomes:
data: $('#formID').serialize(),

Comment: but how do i retrieve it in my controller? the data